# How much do I NEED to know to make a 2D game engine?

Tags: logic, game-engine

I rendered a sprite. After the object is rendered, I can manipulate the points in the object to add animation. Adding a large amount of variables will tell how the rendered object interacts with other objects. A 2d game running with sprites would not need lighting or textures, only the sprites and variables. Is this really all I need to know to make a game engine? **Is manipulating various variables, and rendering sprites all I need to know**? I feel like it is too easy that way. And I also don't know where and **how can I learn everything else about Java**?

Comment: 'how can I learn everything else about Java?' 
I don't think anyone would be able to learn everything.
As for the game engine it really depends on what you want it to do.

Comment: Nic, So far I learned a very basic amount of Java, and there isn't any long tutorial series online that I can find to teach me the more complex code used for Java. **How do I learn more when I run out of tutorials?**

Comment: There are no shortage of tutorials for java online. There are also many books about java. Far more than anyone could be expected to read. If you run out of tutorials to use, the best way to learn is through trial and error. Find some problems to solve and try to code them up. Or find something you want to make and try and make it.

Comment: @Ccflier While self-promotion should be limited, I should mention that I have made a tutorial specifically for people in your situation that are looking to start learning the basics of making games.  Check for me on YouTube ("southpawhare") and look up my video on "The Black Box Project."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends on what you consider an "*engine*."**  Virtually any boiler-plate code or core framework of a game can be called an engine in the most literal, technical sense.  What you described could very well be a suitable engine for the purposes you need it for - *until you find out that it isn't*.

It is likely that these fundamental skills will allow you to make a simple game, and it will be a great learning experience for you in expanding your knowledge.  However, **you will undoubtedly find that there is more to learn as you progress**.

So, in summary, **it will probably not be enough for a very complex game, but it is nonetheless where you should start anyway**, and use it to learn in baby steps.

Comment: I will find out that I have more to learn, but where am I going to go to learn it? If I am only relying on what other people put up online, or what a textbook teaches, I will hit a wall where there are no more recourses to leach off of, and I either end up with only the absolute basics, or the bare minimum for what I need.

Comment: From my own personal experience, the greatest source of skill-building in the field of game development has come from my college academic community.  An education in an environment surrounded by like-minded individuals is absolutely the best step, but if that is not currently available to you, search for clubs or groups in your local area.  People and social interaction with others who also love game development is invaluable.

Comment: @Ccflier gamedev.net is another good resource. Stackexchange also has a game development section: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. If you do a google search on 'game development' there are a number of other resources. Game Coding Complete (McShaffry & Graham) is a book that I'd highly recommend if you want to get in to serious engine development. There are books on every niche subject that you can think of on game development and a lot of them are really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating variables is all you need for any code. Even rendering sprites is loading and modifying variables. The thing you need to know is *which* variables you want to add/manipulate.

To make a game engine you need to first consider what you want it to do, and plan out what variables you need and functions you want it to perform. Once you have this you can begin implementing it.

There are quite a few game engines around however, and re-inventing the wheel is never advised. If you want a 2d game engine to look at, [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) is fairly good for java and will have all the stuff you want for a basic 2D game.